# How to rename files located on a network path (UNC path) in Windows 7 command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, rename

In the command prompt, I need a way up rename a file on a remote server.  Conceptually, this is what I am looking for:

```
ren \\servername\folder\file.txt \\servername\folder\file2.txt
```

Aside from using PSTools, is there a way to do this locally from the C: drive?  I think I can also map a network folder to a drive letter and do it that way, but this batch file I am using needs to be usable by everyone and can't require the user to map a drive.  If that is the *only* way then I guess I'll have to go with it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do not use a full path for the second argument. Only the first argument requires a full path. Windows assumes since you are renaming, the file will remain in the same folder as previously specified. It mentions this in the command help at the bottom:

```
C:\Users\John>ren /?
Renames a file or files.

RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.
REN [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.

Note that you cannot specify a new drive or path for your destination file.
```

e.g.:

```
ren \\servername\folder\file.txt file2.txt
```

Alternatively you can map a drive letter to the UNC share and then issue a command such as:

```
ren Z:\file.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the ren command, you can use the DOS move command to achieve the same result, and full paths are accepted for both arguments:

```
move \\server\share\path\to\file.txt \\server\share\path\to\file.csv
```